# Hi vs Lo Freq Distance Correction on Close-Mic'd material

Tags: mixing, acoustics, reverb, equalization, convolution

The only person I can find who has relevant information on corrective EQ for distance and depth placement in mixing is Beat Kaufmann. He suggests to attenuate high frequencies when intending to place dry signals further back in a mix, however, low frequencies also attenuate with distance, from what I have been able to observe. I have many close-mic'd libraries and instruments in my virtual instrument arsenal, and every time I attenuate their low end, I find myself unable to do so convincingly due so.

Why is it that my low frequencies are harder to realistically correct with EQ for distance perception than higher ones?

Comment: what sort of distances are you referring to?

Comment: Scoring stage and concert hall type distances, so 0-200ft away would be the relative figure